# Example of measures being ergodic but not invariant

Tags: measure-theory, operator-theory, ergodic-theory

Let $\mu$ be a measure, $f:X\rightarrow X$ being a map and $\Sigma$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

> $\mu$ is $f$-**invariant** if $\mu(E) = \mu(f^{-1}(E)), \forall E\in \Sigma$.
>
> $\mu$ is **ergodic** with respect to $f$ if   for every $E\in \Sigma $ with $f^{-1}(E) = E$, either $\mu(E)=1$ or $0$.

It looks like since $f^{-1}(E) = E$ so $\mu(E) = \mu(f^{-1}(E))$, $\mu$ being ergodic implies $\mu$ being $f$-invariant.

Is it true? or is there any counter-example to this claim?

Comment: Ergodicity is defined only when you have measure preserving transformations. Another name for such transformations is $f-$invariant. Now what ergodicity says is that if not only $\mu(f^{-1}(A))=\mu(A)$ but also the sets are equal, i.e. $f^{-1}(A)=A$ then $\mu(A)$ is $0$ or $1$.

Comment: @LandonCarter True, if you take two ergodic and measure preserving actions $T_i: X_i \to X_i$, with $i \in \{1,2\}$ their sum $T_1 \oplus T_2: X_1 \sqcup  X_2 \to X_ \sqcup X_2$ is not ergodic but it is still measure preserving. That said , you can study those transformation that preserve the "measure class" ie the null and co-null sets and the notion of ergodicity makes perfect sense in that setting. When i read the question I understood (perhaps wrongly) that the OP was asking for an example of an ergodic action which is not measure-preserving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a biased coin with probabilities $\{p_, 1-p_i\}$ in the $i$-th flip, where $0 < \delta < p_i < 1 - \delta < 1$ and represent heads buy $0$ and tails by $1$.

You can identify the space given by fliping that coin infinitely many times with $([0,1], \mu)$ just as you do in the case of a non-biased coin, i.e: associate $\{0\}\times \{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ with $[0,0.5)$ and $\{1\}\times \{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ with $[0,5,1)$ and continue that process further sub-diving $[0,1]$ into dyadic intervals. Both $\mu$ and the Lebesgue measure $m$ have the same null sets. The action on $[0,1]$ induced by "shifting" the sequence of flips is ergodic, but not measure preserving.

This transformations are called "Bernoulli shifts". It is still reasonable to ask whether there are ergodic transformations that do not admit **any** invariant measure.

Answer (score 2):

Your argument is totally wrong: ergodicity is a condition on all sets $E$ such that $f^{-1}(E)=E$, rather than assertion that any such sets actually exist. 
 Indeed, this statement is false, and counterexamples are extremely easy to come by.  For instance, let $X$ be any finite set, with $\Sigma=\mathcal{P}(X)$ and $\mu$ any probability measure.  Then if $f:X\to X$ is a cyclic permutation of $X$, then $f$ is ergodic (the only invariant sets are $X$ and $\emptyset$), but $\mu$ is not $f$-invariant unless every singleton has the same measure.