# Why do we need a $T$-invariant probability measure to define ergodicity?

Tags: probability-theory, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

I am studying the concepts of ergicity in a dynamic system. Let $(M, \mathcal A)$ be a measurable space and $T: M \to M$ a measurable map. Given a probability measure $P$, we can say that $P$ or $T$ is ergodic if:
$$P(A)= 0 \quad\hbox{ or } \quad P(A)=1, \quad \forall A, \,\, A = T^{-1}(A)$$
But I have seen some books that before giving the definition of ergidicity,  They require that $P$ be a $T-$invariant (or $T$ to be $P$-invariant) in the following sense:
$$P(T^{-1}(A))= P(A), \quad \forall A \in \mathcal A\label{I}\tag{I}$$
See, for example, this [book](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/abs/dynamical-systems-and-ergodic-theory/ergodic-measures/701D998FC0FBAD34B90AC0748633AA9F).

However, it seems to me that according of this [topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2911317/example-of-measures-being-ergodic-but-not-invariant), the definition of (\ref{I}) is not necessary.

**Question**

What is the real need to demand (\ref{I}) ?

Why is this necessary?

Comment: You could slightly decrease the hypotheses to "wandering sets are null", aka assuming your system is conservative. The idea is we don't want dissipation: we want to assume our system is closed and particles can't leave nor enter it, only be moved around by the dynamics. You definitely *could* define ergodicity for dissipative systems, but things like the Ergodic theorem won't make much sense (how does one measure a "space average" when particles can enter or leave our space. What are we integrating over?)

Comment: From another perspective, given any measure and any flow, we can flow the measure over time to get a family of measures. If we want our "experiments" to be "comparable" they better be using the same "measuring tools" over time. This is exactly the same as asking that the measure be invariant.

Comment: The common example I give to students when teaching ergodic theory is to imagine a closed box with a small vial of an ideal gas inside it. Now imagine the vial is broken, and the gas is allowed to expand throughout the box. Ergodic theory tries to formalize properties of such systems. In your case, a measure preserving transformation corresponds to the box being closed: we can't "lose" or "gain" mass, only move it around. The other half of ergodicity says it must "spread out", since if the mass in a region doesn't lower over time then either we are looking at the whole box (again, using...

Comment: ... measure preserving, i.e. that the box is closed), or we must be looking at a negligible amount of mass (the most obvious example being the boundary of the box, which is of measure zero and can't have mass spreading out further because, again, the box is closed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are completely right, **the notion of ergodic measure does not require an invariant measure**. This is particularly useful in statistical physics since sometimes it is convenient to consider **noninvariant** Gibbs measures.
For example, with such general notion:

1. we can show that a measure is ergodic if and only if any invariant function is constant almost everywhere;
2. and so many times we can establish ergodicity (even of noninvariant measures) by looking at Fourier coefficients.

Nevertheless, it is true that the most interesting consequences come when the ergodic measure is also invariant. For example, for an **ergodic invariant measure** it follows from Birkhoff's ergodic theorem that the time average along almost all trajectories is equal to the space average.